# R2 score output does not return anything in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to find out the `r2_score` of my model but when I run the code it does not return anything.

```
X = df['GrLivArea'].values
y = df['SalePrice'].values


'''
        Split the data set into the training and the test set 
'''
#random_state=0 allows python to randomly select which entries to split 
#test_size=0.3 tests about 30% of the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

#fitting ML into the training model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train)

#Predict the test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_train.reshape(-1,1))

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
scoretest = r2_score(y_train, y_pred)
```

The code in question here is the last line:

```
scoretest = r2_score(y_train, y_pred)
```

Is the issue that I don't have a model after writing the code? I was able to run and find regression and coefficients so I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: what get stored in your variable `scoretest` ?

Comment: When i ran the code this came up
```

In [5]: runfile('C:/Dataset/z5117507.py', wdir='C:/Dataset')
in [6]:
```
No value has been given to me

Answer (score 0):

Its Working Right check you data set else mention your dataset

```
df=pd.read_csv("Iris.csv")

X = df['SepalLengthCm'].values
y = df['SepalWidthCm'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
             X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train)


y_pred = regressor.predict(X_train.reshape(-1,1))

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
scoretest = r2_score(y_train, y_pred)
```

Output: **0.005205152400521662**

Comment: I see, does that mean that my r2 score is 0 and maybe the model does not fit what i am trying to predict?

Comment: yes cross check the values of x and y before fitting

Comment: If the R2 value is 0 is means that you have 100 present  right prediction  its not possible

Comment: The problem  is with you dataset